# Why pdftops gives extra padding but pdf2ps doesn't?

Tags: pdf, ps, utilities

I tried both **pdftops** and **pdf2ps** to convert a pdf figure(no text) into eps.
**pdf2ps** created a ps figure same to the original one, but the ps file produced by **pdftops** contains an extra white padding/margin surrounding the original figure. Is it normal for **pdftops** ? If so, does that mean I have to crop the extra padding/margin every time after I use **pdftops**  ?

remark: **pdftops** generates a smaller file(about half size) than **pdf2ps**.

Comment: Would you please share the commands you used for printing?

Comment: I did pdftops file.pdf and then just opened/clicked the output ps file in Preview.

Comment: pdftops and pdf2ps are different in there behaviour. You have to adjust the margins. Try the solution below and let me know, we can tweak the command for you ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The `pdf2ps` tool is based on [Ghostscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghostscript), a PostScript interpreter. It is actually a fairly thin shell script wrapper around the "gs" tool. While, `pdftops` is a tool comes with `Xpdf` or is successor [Poppler](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/) (e.g. on Ubuntu 9.10, it's part of the "poppler-utils" package).

`pdftops`, by default, output is cropped to the CropBox specified in the PDF file. The option `nocrop` disables cropping. Also, y default, pages larger than the paper are shrunk to fit. so the option `-noshrink` block scaling on PDF pages which are larger than the paper.

```
pdftops -paper A4 -nocrop -noshrink <INPUT_PDF_FILE> <OUTPUT_PS_FILE>
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Unfortunately, the command didn't work as the output still contains white margin around the original figure.

Comment: Is this problem with all the PDF files? Did you try to convert another PDF to PS and you got corped images?

Comment: Yes, it's independent of which pdf file I use.

Comment: Ah. Is it protected by a password, I mean the PDF file, is it protected? Do you have PDF printer. If so try to print this PDF file to another new PDF then convert the new PDF to PS? let's see  ;-)

Comment: Good point. However, weird thing happened as I printed it: the new pdf looks different from the original one with extra white margins added in the new pdf. Does it have something to do with how the original pdf was created? I created the original pdf from a jpg picture which was a screenshot (with selected region). The new pdf just contains unselected part!

Comment: @booksee welcome ;-) I belive you need to adjust the dimensions of the jpg images before you create the PDF file.